# JaCoCo test coverage issue maven build failing

Tags: maven, lombok, jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin

I'm facing the below issue,

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.8:run (default) on project VstsReport: An Ant BuildException has occured: Error while creating report

[ERROR] around Ant part ...... @ 8:11 in /__w/49/s/target/antrun/build-main.xml: Error while analyzing myapp/target/demo.war@WEB-INF/lib/lombok-1.16.22.jar@lombok/eclipse/agent/EclipseLoaderPatcherTransplants.SCL.lombok. Can't add different class with same name: lombok/eclipse/agent/EclipseLoaderPatcherTransplants

[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.

[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

I have tried excluding the class from Jacoco configuration in pom.xml but still facing the issue.

**<exclude>lombok/eclipse/agent/EclipseLoaderPatcherTransplants.class</exclude>**

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue with gradle, you'll need to exclude the jar as follow.

run gradle with --stacktrace option to get more log output.

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Error while analyzing profilecleaner-1.0.jar@BOOT-INF/lib/lombok-1.16.4.jar@lombok/eclipse/agent/EclipseLoaderPatcherTransplants.SCL.lombok with JaCoCo 0.8.8.202204050719/5dcf34a.
        at org.jacoco.core.analysis.Analyzer.analyzerError(Analyzer.java:163)
        at org.jacoco.core.analysis.Analyzer.analyzeClass(Analyzer.java:135)
        at org.jacoco.core.analysis.Analyzer.analyzeClass(Analyzer.java:158)
        at org.jacoco.core.analysis.Analyzer.analyzeAll(Analyzer.java:195)
        at org.jacoco.core.analysis.Analyzer.analyzeZip(Analyzer.java:267)
        at org.jacoco.core.analysis.Analyzer.analyzeAll(Analyzer.java:198)
        at org.jacoco.core.analysis.Analyzer.analyzeZip(Analyzer.java:267)
        at org.jacoco.core.analysis.Analyzer.analyzeAll(Analyzer.java:198)
        at org.jacoco.ant.ReportTask.createBundle(ReportTask.java:573)
        at org.jacoco.ant.ReportTask.createReport(ReportTask.java:545)
        at org.jacoco.ant.ReportTask.execute(ReportTask.java:496)
        ... 150 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't add different class with same name: lombok/eclipse/agent/EclipseLoaderPatcherTransplants
        at org.jacoco.core.analysis.CoverageBuilder.visitCoverage(CoverageBuilder.java:106)
        at org.jacoco.core.analysis.Analyzer$1.visitEnd(Analyzer.java:100)
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor.visitEnd(ClassVisitor.java:377)
        at org.jacoco.core.internal.flow.ClassProbesAdapter.visitEnd(ClassProbesAdapter.java:100)
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:748)
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:424)
        at org.jacoco.core.analysis.Analyzer.analyzeClass(Analyzer.java:117)
        at org.jacoco.core.analysis.Analyzer.analyzeClass(Analyzer.java:133)
        ... 159 more
```

and to exclude the jar

```
jacocoTestReport{
    doFirst {
        delete fileTree (dir: "${buildDir}/resources/main", include: "profilecleaner*.jar")
    }
}
```